# How can I reset my Button count to 0 in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin

I have created a button to count the number of maximum clicked and How can I create another button to reset it to 0 after clicking?

Secondly I want all my buttons to be in Circle shape and Horizontally left and right.

This is the example of my page:

CountPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10">
                                    <Label Text="0" x:Name="labelCount" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                    <Button Text="Count" Clicked="Increment"/>
                                </StackLayout>
```

CountPage.xaml.cs

```
int labelValue = 0;
        public CountPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelValue++;
            labelCount.Text = labelValue.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the circle buttons, I recommend reading [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/geometries#clip-with-a-geometry)

Now let's go to the coding part

First, let's add another button

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10">                                        
  <Label Text="0" x:Name="labelCount" ... />
  <Button Text="Count" Clicked="Increment"/>
  <Button Text="Reset counter" Clicked="Reset"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Now in the code behind you will have to add

```
private void Reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   labelValue=0;
   labelCount.Text = labelValue.ToString(); //this will be 0
}
```

So it's just using the same variable and the name of the other button.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It's done now. I'm really appreciate. Please, what of if I want to calculate in a single button with a minimum count like 0/4 to show in one button. (Meaning that the maximum number to be touch in a button should not be more than 4).

Comment: And what happens when you reach 4? It reset itself or just stop counting? In either case you can do that in the code behind. Just add an `if` conditional

Comment: No all is fine even when it reach 4 or more than that It reset itself. Thank you once again.  I only want you to help me with another question.

Comment: This is the question: what of if I want to calculate in a single button with a minimum count like 1-4 to show in one button. (Meaning that the maximum number to be touch in a button should not be more than 4).

Comment: Then after certain condition, you should do `MyButtonToDisable.IsEnabled = False;` And the button will be shown as disabled